# json return [object object] on submit click

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am passing form details from ionic to php file throuugh controller. If I enter the form data directly through postman, It gets stored. But when I try it by filling the form data I get this error:

Whenever, I click the submit button, I get this error in alert box.-[object object]

```
I have also added the header in php but still am getting the error and alert box shows null. The data to be returned shows null all the time. I am not able to figure out the problem. Please help!!!
```

Here is my php code where I am adding the access control allow header

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');

require_once 'db_functions.php';
$db = new db_functions();
// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if ( isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['contact']) && isset($_POST['gender']) && isset($_POST['user_name']) && isset($_POST['password']) ) 
{

if(is_numeric($_POST['name']) && is_numeric($_POST['gender']))
{
$response["status"] = false;
$response["error_msg"] = "Name and gender cannot have numeric values";
echo json_encode($response);
}
if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
$response["status"] = false;
$response["error_msg"] = "Enter a valid email id";
echo json_encode($response);
}
else
{

// receiving the GET params
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
// check if user is already existed with the same email
if ($db->isUserExisted($user_name)) {
// user already existed
$response["error"] = false;
$response["error_msg"] = "User already existed with " . $user_name;
echo json_encode($response);
} 
else if ($db->isUserEmailExisted($email)) {
// user already existed
$response["error"] = false;
$response["error_msg"] = "User already existed with " . $email;
echo json_encode($response);
}
else if ($db->isUserContactExisted($contact)) {
// user already existed
$response["error"] = false;
$response["error_msg"] = "User already existed with " . $contact;
echo json_encode($response);
}
else {
// create a new user
$user = $db->storeUser($name, $email,$contact,$gender,$user_name,$password);
if ($user) {
// user stored successfully
$response["error"] = true;
$response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
$response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
$response["user"]["contact"] = $user["contact"];
$response["user"]["gender"] = $user["gender"];
$response["user"]["user_name"] = $user["user_name"];
$response["user"]["encrypted_password"] = $user["encrypted_password"];
$response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
$response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
echo json_encode($user);
} else {
// user failed to store
$response["error"] = false;
$response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
echo json_encode($response);
}
}
}
} else {
$response["error"] = false;
$response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters are missing!";
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

This is my controller code

```
 angular.module('app.controllers', [])

.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope) {

})

.controller('selectYourRoleCtrl', function($scope) {

})

.controller('userDetailsCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
$scope.users = {};
$scope.users.gender = "Male";
$scope.regUser = function(){
$http.post("http://localhost/drmedic/register_user.php",$scope.users)
.success(function(data){
alert(data);
})
.error(function(data){
alert(data);
});
}
})

.controller('doctorDetailsCtrl', function($scope) {

})
```

Comment: try this $http.post("http://localhost/drmedic/register_user.php",$scope.users)
.success(function(response){
alert(response.data);
})

Comment: You do `alert(data)` data is an object so your alert is saying "You told me to alert about an object". Don't see anything wrong with that. Perhaps you need to change the response type to prevent JS from parsing the response as JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alert a object only return 'object Object"

```
var bla = {
    'la1': 'la',
    'la2': 'la'
};
alert(bla);
```

Return "object Object". If you turn to.

```
var bla = {
    'la1': 'la',
    'la2': 'la'
};
alert(bla['la1']);
```

Return "la". 
if you need you can do.

```
var string = '';
var bla = {
    'la1': 'la1',
    'la2': 'la2'
};
for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    string += bla['la'+i];
}
alert(string);
```

This will return la1la2

Comment: still getting the same alert.. and no error in php code as well. Please help